# Keras - Create a "generator" to train and fit images by chunk of data

Tags: keras, generator, image-segmentation

;)

I've this issue to create a "Generator" to train a huge amount of Data.
I've 100K images, about 400Gb of data

My pipeline is a kind like :

```
1.Load A Batch of Images Into Memory (m images)
2.Preprocess Batch of Images
3.Augment Batch of Images
4.Infer and Update Model Using Batch of Images
5.Clear Memory and Start Again
6.Continues Until the Epoch is Complete and Then Usually the Data Is Shuffled (Or It's Done During The Epoch s Number of Examples Ahead)
```

A dataframe containining one variable "image_path" with path for images in folder, and targets are OHE variables O, 1, 2, 3
ex :

```
image_path           0 1 2 3
../images/img1.png   0 0 1 0
../images/img1.png   1 0 1 0
```

I've build 3 Functions:

One function to Preprocess Images

```
def preprocess_hflip(size, train_img_names, test=False):
    x_train = []
    for i in train_img_names:
        x_train.append(open_multilayer_image_aug_hflip(i, size, test))
        
    x_train = np.array(x_train)
    #print("x_train_shape : ",x_train.shape)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    return x_train
```

Second function to load images and resize

```
def open_multilayer_image_aug_hflip(path, SIZE, test=False):
    #fullpath = root_train_directory+path
    #print(path)
    fullpath = path
    if test:
        img = plt.imread(fullpath)
        img = cv2.resize(img, SIZE)
        ni = np.zeros((SIZE[0],SIZE[1],3), 'uint8')
        ni[..., 0] = img*255
        #print(img)
    else : 
        if fullpath[-3:] == '.png':
            img = plt.imread(fullpath) ## reading from "image_path" on dataframe
            img = cv2.resize(red, SIZE)
            ni = np.zeros((SIZE[0],SIZE[1],3), 'uint8')
            ni[..., 0] = img*255
    return ni

Usage : X_train = preprocess_hflip((128,128), train['image_path'][:100].values)
```

And third function "generator'

```
def  generate_arrays_from_file(df, batchsize):
    #batchsize = 2
    inputs = []
    targets = []
    batchcount = 0
    totbatch = 0
    #while True:
    for k,v in df.iterrows():
        #print(k,v)
        #print(v['image_path'], v[3:])
        inputs.append(v['image_path'])
        targets.append(v[3:])
        batchcount += 1
        #print("BatchCount ", batchcount)
        if batchcount >= batchsize:
            totbatch = batchcount +  totbatch
            #print("BatchCount > batchSize", batchcount, batchsize)
            print("Total files traités :", totbatch)
            X = np.array(inputs)
            y = np.array(targets, dtype='float32')
            #print(y)
            yield (X, y)
            inputs = []
            targets = []
            batchcount = 0
```

I did lots of testing but I can't get the expected results,
The closest I got from the pipeline

```
1.Load A Batch of Images Into Memory (m images) - OK
2.Preprocess Batch of Images - OK
3.Augment Batch of Images - Ok
4.Infer and Update Model Using Batch of Images - OK
5.Clear Memory and Start Again - OK
6.Continues Until the Epoch is Complete and Then Usually the Data Is Shuffled (Or It's Done During The Epoch s Number of Examples Ahead) - Fail
```

I was just able to train first epoch with this first try, but when first epoch terminates the train also ends. I need to loop this training, with chunk of "batch size" until complete the number of all epochs, in this case 10.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
monGenerateur = generate_arrays_from_file(train[:40], 8)
for X,y in monGenerateur:
    #print(X, y.shape, type(y))
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    train_generator = datagen.flow(preprocess_hflip( (128,128), X), # X Comes from Generator
                               y,
                               batch_size=64,
                               shuffle=True,
                               seed=42)

    valid_generator = datagen.flow(preprocess_hflip(1, (128,128), test['image_path'].values, 'test'),
                               test.iloc[:,3:22].values)


    #for i in range(10):
    hist_1 = model.fit(train_generator, 
          batch_size = 64, 
          epochs=10,
          steps_per_epoch = 10,
          validation_data = next(valid_generator),
          validation_steps=10,
          shuffle=True,
          callbacks = [rlr,ckp,es],
          verbose = 2
             )
```

Below a screenshot from training process

```
Total files traités : 8
Epoch 1/10
10/10 - 2s - loss: 0.2214 - BinaryCrossentropy: 0.2201 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - binary_accuracy: 0.9474 - AUC: 0.5677 - val_loss: 0.2184 - val_BinaryCrossentropy: 0.2173 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9474 - val_AUC: 0.6311
Total files traités : 16
Epoch 1/10
10/10 - 2s - loss: 0.2113 - BinaryCrossentropy: 0.2103 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - binary_accuracy: 0.9474 - AUC: 0.7266 - val_loss: 0.2094 - val_BinaryCrossentropy: 0.2080 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9474 - val_AUC: 0.6311
Total files traités : 24
```

The issue is obvious, It just iterate through the output from the "monGenerateu" 8 times 5.
I also dis another test, calling the preprocess inside the Generator

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
def  generate_arrays_from_file(df, batchsize):
    #batchsize = 2
    inputs = []
    targets = []
    batchcount = 0
    totbatch = 0
    #while True:
    for k,v in df.iterrows():
        #print(k,v)
        #print(v['image_path'], v[3:])
        inputs.append(v['image_path'])
        targets.append(v[3:])
        batchcount += 1
        print("BatchCount ", batchcount)
        if batchcount >= batchsize:
            totbatch = batchcount + totbatch
            print("BatchCount > batchSize", batchcount, batchsize)
            print("Total files traités :", totbatch)
            X = preprocess_hflip((128,128), inputs)
            #X = np.array(inputs)
            y = np.array(targets, dtype='float32')
            #y = np.asarray(targets)
            print(X.shape, y.shape)
            yield (X, y)
            inputs = []
            targets = []
            batchcount = 0
```

But the result is, it loops through the images and when reaches the total batch size starts training, and That's not what I expect, I expect Training for each chunk of data and keep training until complete all epochs.

Any help is appreciated